# SSMS Results Grid

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, wpf-controls, ssms

We are creating an WPF Query builder application that reads data from SQL Server. We will be reading millions of rows sometimes. I am very impressed with the Results grid of SSMS or Visual Studio's SQL Server Object explorer's query window.

How do I get same kind of performance that SSMS to render the results. I know keeping it light is one of the answers but I want to know if someone has suggestions to get the same kind of performance in the WPF data grid or any other data grid that can you used with WPF.

Thanks in advance.

Cheers!

Comment: you don't (usually) need to display millions of rows in a grid. It would be poor interface design...

Comment: I agree. But I want to perform the same functionality as in SSMS. What if the users runs a SELECT *. Will SSMS limit the results?

Comment: Essentially I looking for best practices in WPF that would give the same performance as SSMS. How does SSMS pull data from the server? In small chunks or one shot things like that. So that I can handle it in similar way in my application.

Comment: search for Data Virtualization in wpf, something like this 

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34405/WPF-Data-Virtualization

Comment: SSMS Grid is "just" a .NET custom control that draws/edits what is seen on the screen at a given moment in time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44360824/grid-control-in-ssms